# How can I implement a Fisher-Yates shuffle in Scala without side effects?

Tags: scalaz, state-monad, st-monad, starray, scala-cats

I want to implement the Fisher-Yates algorithm (an in-place array shuffle) without side effects by using an `STArray` for the local mutation effects, and a functional random number generator

```
type RNG[A] = State[Seed,A]
```

to produce the random integers needed by the algorithm.

I have a method `def intInRange(max: Int): RNG[Int]` which I can use to produce a random `Int` in [0,max).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

> ```
> To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
>     for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
>         j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
>         exchange a[j] and a[i]
> ```

I suppose I need to stack `State` with `ST` somehow, but this is confusing to me.  Do I need a `[S]StateT[ST[S,?],Seed,A]`?  Do I have to rewrite `RNG` to use `StateT` as well?

(Edit) I don't want to involve `IO`, and I don't want to substitute `Vector` for `STArray` because the shuffle wouldn't be performed in-place.

I know there is a Haskell implementation [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle), but I'm not currently capable of understanding and porting this to Scalaz.  But maybe you can? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are side-effects you're trying to avoid? I know little about Scala, but at minimum in MT environment you have to lock `i` and modified sequence itself (you're swapping a_i and a_j)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Swapping elements is simple with recursion. To have random numbers without side effects your RNG could have a map function which calls its first-order function with the random number instead of the `getNext...` methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more or less direct translation from the [Haskell version you linked](https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle) that uses a mutable `STArray`. The Scalaz `STArray` doesn't have an exact equivalent of the `listArray` function, so I've made one up. Otherwise, it's a straightforward transliteration:

```scala
import scalaz._
import scalaz.effect.{ST, STArray}
import ST._
import State._
import syntax.traverse._
import std.list._

def shuffle[A:Manifest](xs: List[A]): RNG[List[A]] = {
  def newArray[S](n: Int, as: List[A]): ST[S, STArray[S, A]] =
    if (n <= 0) newArr(0, null.asInstanceOf[A])
    else for {
      r <- newArr[S,A](n, as.head)
      _ <- r.fill((_, a: A) => a, as.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap))
    } yield r
  for {
    seed <- get[Seed]
    n = xs.length
    r <- runST(new Forall[({type λ[σ] = ST[σ, RNG[List[A]]]})#λ] {
      def apply[S] = for {
        g <- newVar[S](seed)
        randomRST = (lo: Int, hi: Int) => for {
          p <- g.read.map(intInRange(hi - lo).apply)
          (a, sp) = p
          _ <- g.write(sp)
        } yield a + lo
        ar  <- newArray[S](n, xs)
        xsp <- Range(0, n).toList.traverseU { i => for {
          j  <- randomRST(i, n)
          vi <- ar read i
          vj <- ar read j
          _  <- ar.write(j, vi)
        } yield vj }
        genp <- g.read
      } yield put(genp).map(_ => xsp)
    })
  } yield r
}
```

Although the asymptotics of using a mutable array might be good, do note that the constant factors of the `ST` monad in Scala are quite large. You may be better off just doing this in a monolithic block using regular mutable arrays. The overall `shuffle` function remains pure because all of your mutable state is *local*.

Comment: Ah thanks — this must be what Travis meant about using a `STRef[Seed]` and an `STArray` in the same `ST`.  Thanks for the point about `ST`'s constant factors.  Also, this rosetta stone enables me to read the Haskell version.

Answer (score 4):

You have lots of options. One simple (but not very principled) one would be just to lift both the `Rng` and `ST` operations into `IO` and then work with them together there. Another would be to use both an `STRef[Long]` and an `STArray` in the same `ST`. Another would be to use a `State[(Long, Vector[A]), ?]`.

You could also use a `StateT[State[Long, ?], Vector[A], ?]` but that would be kind of pointless. You could probably use a  `StateT` (for the RNG state) over an `ST` (for the array), but again, I don't really see the point.

It's possible to do this pretty cleanly without side effects with just `Rng`, though. For example, using [NICTA's RNG library](https://github.com/NICTA/rng):

```
import com.nicta.rng._, scalaz._, Scalaz._

def shuffle[A](xs: Vector[A]): Rng[Vector[A]] =
  (xs.size - 1 to 1 by -1).toVector.traverseU(
    i => Rng.chooseint(0, i).map((i, _))
  ).map {
    _.foldLeft(xs) {
      case ((i, j), v) =>
        val tmp = v(i)
        v.updated(i, v(j)).updated(j, tmp)
    }
  }
```

Here you just pick all your swap operations in the `Rng` monad, and then fold over them with your collection as the accumulator, swapping as you go.

Comment: Thanks Travis — of the 6 possibilities in your answer: I don't want to lift to `IO` (#1), I also don't want to use `Vector`, because then I'm not performing an in-place shuffle, and I think the complexity of the algorithm changes (#3,4,6).  I didn't understand suggestion #2 (`STRef[Long]` and `STArray`); but I think I need #5 (`StateT` over `ST`) to get the in-place update.  Could you elaborate on that answer?  I've updated my question, hopefully it's a little clearer now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is amost the same as Travis solution only difference is that it uses the State monad. I wanted to find a minimal set of imports but I finally gave up:

```
import com.nicta.rng.Rng
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object FisherYatesShuffle {

  def randomJ(i: Int): Rng[Int] = Rng.chooseint(0,i)

  type Exchange = (Int,Int)

  def applyExchange[A](exchange: Exchange)(l: Vector[A]): Vector[A] = {
    val (i,j) = exchange
    val vi = l(i)
    l.updated(i,l(j)).updated(j,vi)
  }

  def stApplyExchange[A](exchange: Exchange): State[Vector[A], Unit] = State.modify(applyExchange(exchange))

  def shuffle[A](l: Vector[A]): Rng[Vector[A]] = {
    val rngExchanges: Rng[Vector[Exchange]] = (l.length - 1 to 1 by -1).toVector.traverseU { i =>
      for {
        j <- randomJ(i)
      } yield (i, j)
    }

    for {
      exchanges <- rngExchanges
    } yield exchanges.traverseU(stApplyExchange[A]).exec(l)
  }

}
```